# Android's openFileInput says No such file or directory but the file is there

Tags: android, file, kotlin, copy

I have a command line utility that produces a file in the app's files directory. I can see that the file is there but openFileInput still cant find it.

The file's name is not very long and it doesnt contain any spaces or special characters. It's an mp4 file.

This code produces the file:

```
  val byteArray = ByteArray(1024)
            try {
                val processBuilder = ProcessBuilder().command(
                    filesDir.absolutePath + File.separator + "start.sh",
                    "args")                       
                ).redirectErrorStream(true)
                    val process = processBuilder.start()
                    val inputStream = process.getInputStream()
                    while (inputStream.read(byteArray) !== -1) {
                        println("Debug: " + String(byteArray))
                    }
                    inputStream.close()
                    process.waitFor()
            } catch (ex: IOException) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
            }
```

And this is the line the crash occurs:

```
var copyToSd = this.openFileInput("myfile.mp4").readBytes()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was incredible...

The command line tool I use accepts the filenames through command line variables. The mistake that I made was to give the args like this:

```
filesDir.absolutePath + File.separator + "start.sh",
                    "arg filenameparameter")
```

instead of this:

```
filesDir.absolutePath + File.separator + "start.sh",
                    "arg",
                    "filenameparameter")
```

That worked but created an extra space at the beginning of the file! The file was there but it couldn't be found because of that extra space.

Amazing